Can't find method MemorySegment.allocateNative in Java 21 build of project Panama
I'm trying to implement java code that make native calls to ioctl. I can´t find a updated documentation for project Panama and it seems that a ton of methods have been removed from the API, one of them being MemorySegment.allocateNative. What is the equivalent to this method in Java 21 build?
I have tried using https://github.com/carldea/panama4newbies?tab=readme-ov-file as reference but it seems to be outdated. The Java Doc in MemorySegment class also has no mentions to allocateNative.

You will save time re-working code later if you avoid preview releases and jump to the delivered releases of Foreign Function / Memory API of JDK22+. Then refer to latest examples, not JDK19 code that won't work in JDK21. Try here

Hello @DuncG! Thank you for your comment. I'll try using JDK 22+! Cheers!
